# Why does it take the T-800 so long to find a car to transport itself to the gun store?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

The Terminator is seen [breaking into a car in broad daylight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQoQFkX0ztY) but we know [arrived at the observatory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67JrUmbydrk) when it was pitch black.

It probably would have had an easier time, and an earlier start to seek out the Sarah Connors when it was still dark out. It may have been able to even get away with breaking into their houses and killing them without being seen.

**Why did it take so long for the Terminator to steal a car?**

Answer (score 5):

The Terminator isn't on a schedule. As far as it's aware, there is no opposition to its plan to kill Sarah Connor so there's no point rushing into things half-assed. It gets some money and some clothes, acquires a vehicle and find somewhere to base itself, then sets off to find some weapons before beginning its sweep.

> He had come down Ventura Canyon Road in the dark, seeing no cars or
> people. He had to walk because the chronoporting had fused electrical
> circuits in a hundred-meter circumference.
>
> So he came down the mountain like an implacable god descending
> Olympus, the ornamental chains on the dead punk’s heavy boots clanking
> with each step. Searching.
>
> **He had an indeterminate time to locate and terminate the target and
> therefore could be thorough in acquiring the proper equipment. His
> clothes were ill fitting, but he would get more later, if necessary.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Terminator: Official Novelisation](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/The_Terminator_(Frakes_novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: What is chronoporting?

Comment: @WantingAnswers Chrono + port. As in time + travel.

Comment: @MishaR - Like teleporting, but temporally rather than spatially.

Comment: Valorum: "He had to walk because the chronoporting had fused electrical circuits in a hundred-meter circumference."

So how does this affect the T-800?

Comment: @WantingAnswers - All the nearby cars wouldn't start. He has to walk down to the (Vermont Canyon) houses at the bottom of the mountain to find a vehicle

Comment: Valorum: Oh, got it.

Comment: Also, you'll notice movies do this a lot where a scene goes very quickly from pitch black night to blazing daylight while perhaps only an hour has passed on-screen. The reason for that is that filming at dusk/dawn sucks - you get a very small window of opportunity to shoot, and it's very hard to make the light look good. You have to take the exact time on screen with at least a grain of salt.

Comment: delinear: It definitely could have been like an hour or two before dawn. Very true.

Comment: @ Wanting Answers; Reese says the terminator was unaffected because the terminator was machine wrapped in flesh, I believe.  Which is hand-wavy as hell, of course, but that was his story to the psychologist.

Comment: @JohnHunt - All the electrical stuff happens before the time traveler arrives

Comment: @ Valorum; True, though it is part of the same process, perhaps like a carrier wave. It was just a thought, not an answer, of course.